# Retrieving data from firebase by the dialog flow inline editor fulfillment

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am just start learning how to write fulfillment to read a data stored in the firebase as a first step.

Actually, I stored the same data in the  firebase realtime database
and the firebase cloud database just to try from which one i must read my data, so I am just stuck how to retrieve it by the inline editor

My data is just a JSON object String names. 
Note : form where i should start to learn Node.js for dialogflow fulfillment to do basic operation as storing and retrieving ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [firebase-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) library for node.js.

The inline editor is just Firebase Cloud Functions under the covers.

Your fulfillment code needs to run "somewhere" in the cloud - you'll need an HTTPS URL that you will provide, so this is called a "webhook". Firebase Cloud Functions are a convenient place to do this - they provide a HTTPS endpoint and good scalability, but you can run your fulfillment webhook anywhere on the public Internet.

Dialogflow provides an easy way to use Firebase Cloud Functions, by providing the inline code editor. This uses Firebase Cloud Functions to do the work, but hides the URL from you, so it is one fewer thing you need to deal with.

There are a number of good places to get started, but one is using [Google's Codelabs for the Assistant](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=Assistant) make sure you also have looked at [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/) for Actions on Google, which links to other resources as well.

Comment: Can you help me with figuring out what is the relation between firebase cloud functions and the fulfillment ? 
I mean learning about firebase cloud function will help me to do what ?
I am working on project as extending some features with  the google  assistant, but still can't know from where to start learning basics and skills to go through.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a little more info. If you do have further, specific, questions, please start a new StackOverflow question.